# Graph API unauthorized error for specific user only

Tags: microsoft-graph, graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api, ms-graph-client, office-graph

[image]

**All the permission are given , this API is working fine for other users**

**Below is the screenshot of Graph explorer calling this API and getting unauthorized error**

**This API was working fine but after changing my outlook password because of some unwanted hack in the organizations**

**Is there any way to solve this problem and getting this issue in this API only other Graph API working fine**

Answer (score 0):

As per your description it seems it is blocked or not allowed by your security ops teams.

I would suggest register an app and use postman instead of graph explorer.